# Rinnai R85 - no power no propane?

Tags: electrical, propane

We have an Rinnai R85, suddenly no power. We do have 120 voltage at unit terminals and both fuses good.

We ran out of propane as well.
Would that have any impact, ie: if no fuel flows, power disabled??

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Rinnai R85 is a tankless water heater, that needs gas to run (Heats water). It will shut off if no gas present.

Comment: Assuming you got more propane, the unit may have locked out and you'll need to reset it.

Comment: The electrical power is just to run the controls.  It is the propane that heats the water and does the work.  Once the propane tank is filled, it will take a few minutes at least to fill the lines from the tank to the heater.  Should have instructions on how to restart the the heater.